# How download files from List and show progress in progress bar

Tags: c#

In my app i have a list with links.

```
 public List<string> Urls ()
    {
        var list = new List<string>();
        list.Add("http://example.com/image.jpg");
        list.Add("http://example.com/image1.jpg");
        list.Add("http://example.com/image2.jpg");

        return list;
    }
```

I use a webclient for downloading.

```
 private void downloadAlbum_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      foreach (var link in Urls())
         {
          using (var wc = new WebClient())
                {
                    wc.DownloadFile(link.ToString(),fileName);
                }
         }
}
```

But, my winform is lagging. While WebClient do this work.
Maybe anyone have a example for async function with multiple download and show current progress in progress bar?
Update.
I have async await for one file

```
 private void Downloader(string link, string filepath)
    {
        using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
        {
            wc.DownloadProgressChanged += Wc_DownloadProgressChanged;
            wc.DownloadFileCompleted += Wc_DownloadFileCompleted;
            wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(link), filepath);
        }
    }

private void Wc_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, 
DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }

 private void Wc_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar.Value = 0;

        if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Canceled", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return;
        }

        if (e.Error != null) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Somethings wrong, check your internet","Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            return;
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Download is done!", "Message",MessageBoxButtons.OK,MessageBoxIcon.Information);

    }
```

Comment: Have you tried using `async` and failed to do so? It's better to show some efforts from your side since it seems you already know what to do.

Comment: Make downloading from separate thread and then adjust progress value with dispatcher

Comment: Why are you declaring a new list inside of the list then returning it? Wouldn't it will lose scope?

Comment: Any help wich can improve my coding skill will be usefull for me:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Progress value:

```
Tuple<DateTime, long, long> DownloadingProgress = new Tuple<DateTime, long, long>(DateTime.MinValue, 0, 0);
DownloadingProgress = new Tuple<DateTime, long, long>(DateTime.Now, 0, 0);
```

Before you start to download use this:

```
Wc.DownloadProgressChanged += DownloadProgressChanged; //when you start download
```

And here DownloadProgressChanged

```
private void DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs downloadProgressChangedEventArgs)
{
     DownloadingProgress = new Tuple<DateTime, long, long>(DateTime.Now, downloadProgressChangedEventArgs.TotalBytesToReceive, downloadProgressChangedEventArgs.BytesReceived);
}
```

So you can see the progress with percent:

```
Console.WriteLine("Downloading: " + ((DownloadingProgress.Item3 * 100) / DownloadingProgress.Item2) + "% - " + DownloadingProgress.Item2 + " / " + DownloadingProgress.Item3);
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use **System.Net.Http.HttpClient** instead of WebClient because when you tried to download files asynchronously best practice to use **System.Net.Http.HttpClient**.

I found idea behind this in link : [HttpClientDownload](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/6849)

For downloading list of files you have to use:

```
private async void DownloadFiles(List<Uri> urls)
    {
        try
        {
            Progress<double> progress = new Progress<double>();
            foreach (Uri uri in urls)
            {
                if (!client.isProcessCancel)
                {
                    //Gets download progress - pgrBarDowload is our Progress Bar
                    progress.ProgressChanged += (sender, value) => pgrBarDowload.Value = (int)value;
                }

                var cancellationToken = new CancellationTokenSource();

                writeOperation("Downloading File: " + uri.OriginalString);

                //Set files in download queue
                client.isProcessCancel = false;
                await client.DownloadFileAsync(uri.OriginalString, progress, cancellationToken.Token, directoryPath);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            writeOperation(ex.Message);
        }
}
```

This method will download provided files asynchronously:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
public async Task DownloadFileAsync(string url, IProgress<double> progress, CancellationToken token, string fileDirectoryPath)
    {
        using (HttpResponseMessage response = httpClient.GetAsync(url, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead).Result)
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            //Get total content length
            var total = response.Content.Headers.ContentLength.HasValue ? response.Content.Headers.ContentLength.Value : -1L;
            var canReportProgress = total != -1 && progress != null;
            using (Stream contentStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(), fileStream = new FileStream(fileDirectoryPath + url.Substring(url.LastIndexOf('/') + 1), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.ReadWrite, 8192, true))
            {
                var totalRead = 0L;
                var totalReads = 0L;
                var buffer = new byte[8192];
                var isMoreToRead = true;

                do
                {
                    var read = await contentStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    if (read == 0)
                    {
                        isMoreToRead = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, read);

                        totalRead += read;
                        totalReads += 1;

                        if (totalReads % 2000 == 0 || canReportProgress)
                        {
                            //Check if operation is cancelled by user
                            if (!isProcessCancel)
                            {
                                progress.Report((totalRead * 1d) / (total * 1d) * 100);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                progress.Report(100);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                while (isMoreToRead);
            }
        }
}
```

Note: Progress Bar will show progress for each file individually. This code is tested for Large Media files too. You can also set Progress for all files together by Calculating files size before download start.

I have created small demonstration in c# WinForm application related to Files download, Download progress and File Operations. Please follow below link: [enter link description here](https://github.com/sachetpatil1/DownloadMultipleAsync)

Please feel free comment any suggestions or doubts.